# No back button on UINavigationBar inside UITabbarController

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uinavigationbar

I am working on an app for `iOS6` and `iOS7`. I just found a weird behavior that varies between the two versions.

My app has a `UITabbarController` with 3 tabs and each tab as `UINavigationController` in it.

On `iOS6` when I do a `push` on any of these `navControllers` the 2nd `ViewController` after the `root` does not show a `back` button in the `navigationBar`. However any subsequent pushes show the `back` button.

On `iOS7`, however, I see a back button with no title after 1st push and a back button with title `"Back"` after subsequent push.

Is this behavior normal? I can't understand why this is happening. How do I make sure I have a back button after every push irrespective of the `OS` version.

---

**EDIT**

Here is some code for clarity :

This is how I am initiating the `UITabBarController`

```
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {

        NSMutableArray *vcs = @[].mutableCopy;

        JBNavigationVC *navVC = nil;

        if ([JBUser sharedInstance].isLoggedIn) {
            _productCategoryVC = [[JBProductCategoryVC alloc] init];
            _productCategoryVC.title = @"Products";
            navVC = [[JBNavigationVC alloc] initWithRootViewController:_productCategoryVC];
            [vcs addObject:navVC];

            _triviaVC = [[JBTriviaVC alloc] init];
            _triviaVC.title = @"Trivia";
            navVC = [[JBNavigationVC alloc] initWithRootViewController:_triviaVC];
            [vcs addObject:navVC];

            _infoVC = [[JBInfoVC alloc] init];
            _infoVC.title = @"Info";
            navVC = [[JBNavigationVC alloc] initWithRootViewController:_infoVC];
            [vcs addObject:navVC];
        }
        self.viewControllers = vcs;
    }
    return self;
}
```

JBNavigationVC is a subclass of `UINavigationController`. This is how I transition to the `tabbarVC` in `AppDelegate`

```
    _tabBarVC = [[JBTabBarVC alloc] init];
    [_tabBarVC setSelectedIndex:0];
    [self.window setRootViewController:_tabBarVC];
```

This sets the first `VC` to front. This VC is has a `UITableView` in it and in `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` I do this:

```
if (!_productsListVC) {
    _productsListVC = [[JBProductsListVC alloc] init];
}
_productsListVC.category = category;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:_productsListVC animated:YES];
```

Comment: I think we'll need to see some code to figure this one out.  Have you tried changing the title of your root view controller(s) or the second view controller(s)?

Comment: @JonathanArbogast added some code as per request. Hope this helps